# Unable to install plasma-nm, returning an error 'E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)'. Please help

Tags: apt, dpkg, kde

When I try to install plasma-nm through terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install plasma-nm
```

or to perform `autoremove`

```
sudo apt-get autoremove,
```

I am receiving the following error

```
Removing linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic (4.8.0-46.49) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/lib/modules/4.8.0-46-generic/kernel/drivers/video/fbdev/sis/sisfb.ko': Not a directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I am trying to do the following 
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get install plasma-nm

Comment: Sorry, I should have said please [edit] your question to add information. The error is coming from `autoremove`. I don't understand why dpkg expects that driver to be a directory... Maybe you can try `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic` and then try again

Comment: that has workd out for me.

Comment: Oh that's great :) would you like to write an answer to help others explaining what you did?

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestions received from Zanna, I have tried to reinstall 'linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic' using

*sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic*

and then

*sudo apt-get autoremove*

That solved my probem. I could remove the unnecessary packages